# Comparing 2 list of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I have a list :

```
 a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
 # Stores list of x,y coordinates
```

and a list:

```
 b = [(1, 2), (10, 1), (3, 10), (4, 9)]
```

Now, I want to replace in `a` where it has y coordinate in `a` >= of , `b` with y coordinate + 2.

Since here `a` has an equivalent or greater of `b` in:

```
[(1,2), (3,4)]
```

I want to replace in `a` such that it becomes:

```
a = [(1,4), (3,6), (4,5), (6,7)]
```

How could I do this?

I know there exists a method with numpy such that:

```
np.where(a >= b) , do something;
```

but not sure how could I use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, compare their `axis=1` and `+=2`

```
a = np.asarray(a)
b = np.asarray(b)

a[a[:, 1] > b[:, 1], 1] += 2
```

---

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 6],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

no numpy:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
b = [(1, 2), (10, 1), (3, 10), (4, 9)]
c = [(aa[0], aa[1]+2) if aa[1] >= bb[1] else aa for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]
```

`c` is `[(1, 4), (3, 6), (4, 5), (6, 7)]`